# How to merge two jQuery Datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datepicker

I have two datepickers with different id and name. Can I merge them both and remove the redundant code?

```
     <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery( "#<portlet:namespace/>other_date" ).datepicker({
           showOn: "button",
           buttonImage: "/html/themes/control_panel/images/common/calendar.png",
           buttonImageOnly: true,
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true
       });
      jQuery( "#<portlet:namespace/>bene_relation_birth_date").datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "/html/themes/control_panel/images/common/calendar.png",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
      })
});
</script>
```

...

```
<input type="text" name="other_date" label="" value=""
                    id="other_date"></input>


 <input type="text" name="bene_relation_birth_date" label="" value=""
                    id="bene_relation_birth_date"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select both elements at once and then loop over them with [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Within the loop you apply the datepicker to each element you have selected. You can use the `this` keyword to access the current element in the loop.

Something like this:

```
var selector = "#other_date, #bene_relation_birth_date";

jQuery(selector).each(function(i, elm) {
   jQuery(this).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "/html/themes/control_panel/images/common/calendar.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
  });
});
```